# PHP not getting POST data from $.ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a JavaScript that runs a POST method once my datepicker has been out of focus (I also tried this on a regular submit button) and runs the script `rent-fetch-pick-up-point.php`. The PHP runs, however it doesn't get past the if-statement because my it's not getting the POST data. The datepicker is tied to a input field `time-period-from`

```
datepickerTo.blur(function(){
  if (selectedDateFrom.length > 0) {

    datepickerFrom.delay(500).queue(function(){

      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "include/rent-fetch-pick-up-point.php",
        data: {action: selectedDateFrom},
        success: function(data) {
          $("#pick-up-point-container").html(data);
        }
      });
    });
  }
});
```

Here is the PHP code:

```
if (isset($_POST['time-period-from'])) {
  require '../include/connection.php';

  $dateFrom = $_POST['time-period-from'];
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM order WHERE $dateFrom BETWEEN date_from AND date_to";
  $result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
  $numRows = mysqli_num_rows($result);

  echo $sql; // For testing purposes
}
```

And here's the HTML:

```
  <input type="text" name="time-period-from" id="datepicker-from" class="datepicker"></p>
```

I also tried using $.post() instead of $.ajax(), but I ran into the same issue:

```
$.post("include/rent-fetch-pick-up-point.php", {name: selectedDateTo}, function(data) {

  $("#pick-up-point-container").text(data)

});
```

Comment: You do realize you're sending the data in `action` and not in `time-period-from`?

Comment: Your posting `action`, not `time-period-from`...  try: `$_POST['action']`

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to [SQL-Injections](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says [your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!

Comment: @CharlotteDunois oh, that's what's wrong! I didn't quite understand how or where I was supposed to get the POST data from, but things got a little clearer now. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The keys of `$_POST` come from the keys of the object you pass to the `data:` option, not the names of the form fields where the values originally came from. Since you used:

```
data: { action: selectedDateFrom }
```

the value will be in `$_POST['action']`, not `$_POST['time-period-from']`. So you need to use:

```
if (isset($_POST['action']))
```

and:

```
$dateFrom = $_POST['action'];
```

or you could change the Javascript to:

```
data: { "time-period-from": selectedDateFrom }
```

Comment: I got it working now. Thanks for explaining it thoroughly.

Answer (score 0):

I think your selectedDateFrom variable is array that cause your post info can't you get properly .

```
data: {action: $('#selectedDateFrom').serializeArray()}
```

then you get your form data properly

Comment: Why do you think it's an array?

Comment: you use selectedDateFrom.length that cause i think it is array or string

Comment: My guess is it's a string, probably `$("#selectedDateFrom").val()`.

Comment: I'm not sure why you would use `.serializeArray()` on a single element.

Comment: $("#datepicker-from").val() this process you can easily get this data

Answer (score 0):

You aren't grabbing the right variable on the PHP side:

```
if (isset($_POST['action'])) {
  require '../include/connection.php';

  $dateFrom = $_POST['action'];
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM order WHERE $dateFrom BETWEEN date_from AND date_to";
  $result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
  $numRows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
  echo $sql; // For testing purposes
}
```